# Passing data between storyboards with no segue

Tags: objective-c, ios7, storyboard

Hello I have two story boards. Lets call them storyboard1 and storyboard2.

I want to pass data from storyboard1 to storyboard2, and here is my code.

In storyboard1:

```
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"IndicesDetail" bundle:nil];
DataIntegrationIndexDetailViewController *cl =   (DataIntegrationIndexDetailViewController *)[sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"indicesDetail"];

cl.transitioningDelegate = self;

[self presentViewController:cl animated:YES completion:nil];
```

and in storyboard2, I called the value something like this:

```
NSLog(@"sel index:%@",_delegate.selectedIndexCode);
```

the result I got is null.

I also try like this, in storyboard1:

```
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"IndicesDetail" bundle:nil];
DataIntegrationIndexDetailViewController *cl = (DataIntegrationIndexDetailViewController *)[sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"indicesDetail"];

cl.selectedIndex = @"test";

[self presentViewController:cl animated:YES completion:nil];
```

But it's give me an error.

So how I pass data from one storyboard to another storyboard?

Comment: My approach is using an App Model Class to keep "shared application info". This could be made using a singleton instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:cl animated:YES];
```

instead of `[self presentViewController]`

Comment: He doesn't use segue, so we need to call `pushViewController`

Comment: thanks its solve my problem.. and here is my working code:    UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"IndicesDetail" bundle:nil];
        DataIntegrationIndexDetailViewController *cl = [[DataIntegrationIndexDetailViewController alloc] init];
        
        cl.selectedIndexCode = @"hehe";
        
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:cl animated:YES];

Answer (score 0):

You should understand how to use storboards first. http://www.raywenderlich.com/50308/storyboards-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this would be to use a singleton class...

http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/